# Angular esbuild @angular/compiler missing from bundle file

Tags: angular, angular-cli, micro-frontend, esbuild

I have a shell application that works with https://single-spa.js.org/docs/api/ and https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs to run its various micro-frontends.

Now I have a brand new Angular application and I've wanted to make it worked with the new builder `esbuild`.

Run `npm run build` and end up with a `main.js` file. When I then try to run this file, it produces an error:

> Uncaught Error: The injectable '_G' needs to be compiled using the
> JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available. The injectable
> is part of a library that has been partially compiled. However, the
> Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation
> is used as fallback.
>
> Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become
> fully AOT compiled. Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded
> by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or
> '@angular/platform-server', or manually provide the compiler with
> 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

Shouldn't the bundled file include the @angular/compiler library ?

Edit: Included package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/ngrx-toolkit": "^0.1.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/signals": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.1.1",
    "@signicat/pubsub": "^2.0.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.20.2",
    "esbuild-plugin-manifest": "^1.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "single-spa": "^6.0.1",
    "single-spa-angular": "^9.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
```

Comment: I think that most likely you used a very outdated library that wasn't built with the latest Ivy engine. Angular removed ngcc that previously processed such libraries.

Comment: An outdated library on the shell application or on the Angular app ?

Comment: @Sergey Included package json, but as you see everything is very recent.

Comment: First, I would recommend turning off all optimizations. This will allow you to see what service gets injected. This will help you realize what library is causing the issue. As the error states, it's about _what_ is being injected. Knowing _what_ is, will help you narrow down the search.

Comment: Judging by signle-spa-angular version compatibility this library is the cause of your troubles. Last version mentioned is 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm install @angular/compiler
```

or

```
yarn add @angular/compiler
```

Clear Cache and Reinstall Dependencies

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

or

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```